# ¿Guardar archivo y ruta?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo mi siguiente código:

```
public   class UsrConexion
{
public string cadenaconexion;
protected string sql; 
protected int resultado;
protected SqlConnection cnn;
protected SqlCommand comandosql;
protected string mensaje;
protected string sql1;

public UsrConexion()
    {
    this.cadenaconexion = ("data source=ECRIBOL\\Juan360;initial catalog=Degi;user id=sa;password=12stones.4;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    this.cnn = new SqlConnection(this.cadenaconexion);

}

        }
}`
```

Tengo mis 2 tablas Facturas y Comprador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es guardar los datos, incluyendo el archivo pdf y el id de la tabla de Comprador en un servidor y en el sql guardar su ruta. espero puedan ayudarme. (solo quiero como hacerlo mediante una consulta o un pequeño ejemplo, soy novato y nunca eh trabajo con archivos ni mucho menos con rutas)

Comment: No intentaste nada? y no solamente eso. Estas esperando que te escribamos todo el codigo (en general esperamos que hayas probado algo) y ademas no estas mostrando ni siquiera de donde vienen los datos que tenes que guardar.

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar][ https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla][2]! 


  [1]:
  [2]: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: Ya que estas aprendiendo, aprende buenas practicas de programación te recomiendo estudies y revises estos enlaces, la ruta de tu base de datos la puedes poner en un archivo de configuración App.config http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/07/archivos-de-configuracion-una.html por otro lado estudia ADO.NET aprende las operaciones CRUD http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/01/adonet-parte-5-ejemplos-simples.html tener una clase para manejar la conexión es una pésima idea tarde o temprano te traerán problemas la conexión la puedes declarar en un bloque Using... EndUsing se encargara de cerrar la conexión

Answer (score 1):

Pues mira, no entendí bien. Si lo que queres es guardar el archivo, lo que podes hace es:

utilizar la función OpenFileDialog, para buscar el documento que queres guardar. Por ejemplo:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Archivos PDF|*.pdf";
        open.Title = "Abrir";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            txtFileName.Text = open.FileName;
        }
        open.Dispose();
```

de esa manera, guardas la ruta en un textbox para poder poder ver la ruta y luego utilizarla. Luego para prepararlo para ser guardado en la bd, utilizas la librería System.IO. Lo mejor es que guardes los archivos en formato varbinary(max). Continuando, declaras un arreglo de tipo byte que es el que se asemeja a un varbinary, luego la igualas a un metodo de la librería System.IO que se llama File, al escribir un File. verás una sería de metodos que tiene. lo que vos necesitar es pasarlo a un arreglo de bytes entonces utilizas, File.ReadAllBytes(txtFileName.Text) donde txtFileName.Text ya va a tener la ruta que recogiste del filedialog.

Al final tenes algo así:

```
byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(txtFileName.Text);
```

luego en un query de sql pasas el arreglo como parametro para el campo "Documento" en tu base de datos. (No recordaba el nombre del campo así que lo nombré Documento).

Si solo queres guardar la ruta pues solo pasas de parametro el valor que tenga txtFileName.Text

Espero que te sirva.